# How can I delete all values that have a specific column and row number?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa

This code takes too long time:

```
List<DataLogg> selectedLogger = dataLoggRepository.findByLoggerId(loggerId.getValue());
for(int i = firstIndex-1; i < lastIndex; i++) {
    try {
        DataLogg dataLogg = selectedLogger.get(i);
        if (dataLogg != null) {
            dataLoggRepository.delete(dataLogg);
        }
    } catch(Exception e1) {}
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid this for-loop, and still delete everything between `firstIndex-1` and `lastIndex` that have the column value `loggerId.getValue()`?

Suggestions from the comments below:

```
List<DataLogg> selectedLogger = dataLoggRepository.findByLoggerId(loggerId.getValue());
List<DataLogg> deleteThese = new ArrayList<DataLogg>();
for(int i = firstIndex-1; i < lastIndex; i++) {
    try {
        DataLogg dataLogg = selectedLogger.get(i);
        deleteThese.add(dataLogg);
    } catch(Exception e1) {}
}
dataLoggRepository.deleteInBatch(deleteThese);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218082/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-martensson-how-can-i-delete-all-values-that-hav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another small way to write it.

```
List<DataLogg> selectedLogger = dataLoggRepository.findByLoggerId(loggerId.getValue());
List<DataLogg> deleteThese = IntStream.range(firstIndex - 1, lastIndex).mapToObj(i -> selectedLogger.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
dataLoggRepository.deleteInBatch(deleteThese);
```

Comment: Is a stream faster than a simple for-loop?

Comment: It is more fluent when you read it, an technically talking it's faster. BUT be carefull, my sniped might need sorme adaptation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think streams looks weird and for-loops in C-style seems to be more easier too read.

Comment: Yes but stream are faster and can be parallelized.

Comment: "DataLogg cannot be converted to int" I got an error.

Comment: ".map(i -> selectedLogger.get(i))"

Comment: I already reading the documentation. Just telling other reader in the future that this code does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218218/discussion-between-zorglube-and-daniel-martensson).

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Query(value = "Delete from dataLoggTable where dataLoggTable.id in " +
            "(select id from dataLoggTable offset :firstIndex)", 
            nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void delete(int firstIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a better solution for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use java stream API

```
selectedLogger
.stream()
.skip(firstIndex-2)
.limit(lastIndex-firstIndex+1)
.filter(loggerId.getValue()!=null)
.map(()->{dataLoggRepository.delete(dataLogg);});
```

Comment: That's the same as he already does only in another syntax. Why should it be faster

Comment: maybe use parallelStream() will be faster

Comment: No. Because you will produce many Delete statements. This should be done in one statement

Comment: Hahahahaha, if the loop is ban, the filter and deete logic should be written in DAO layer which is in findByLoggerId() method.