# Best approach to delete 2000 records using JPQL in spring-jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

If in the database table, the records limit exceeds 10000 (10K) , then i need to delete old 2000 (2K) based on timestamp by using JPA name query.

Below are my named queries,

```
@NamedQuery(name = FIND_COMMN_LOG_ID_BY_DEVICE_ID, 
    query = "select entity.id from table1 entity where entity.deviceId =:deviceId ORDER BY recordedTime ASC"),

@NamedQuery(name = DELETE_LOG_BY_DEVICE_ID_BASED_ON_TIMESTAMP, 
    query = "delete from table1 entity where entity.id in (:IdList)")})
```

There are used this way:

```
List<Integer> list = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Constants.FIND_COMMN_LOG_ID_BY_DEVICE_ID)
    .setParameter("deviceId", deviceId)
    .setMaxResults(2000)
    .getResultList();

int count = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Constants.DELETE_LOG_BY_DEVICE_ID_BASED_ON_TIMESTAMP)
    .setParameter("IdList", list)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Above queries are working but i am getting performance issues and it is taking a lot of time to delete 2000 records and server is crashing also.

Can anyone has better simple and fast approach to delete 2000 records?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Did you try creating index on colum "recordedTime"?.
I would go for first approach.

Btw how much time this deletion takes?

Comment: Why not use a delete query directly? `delete top 2000 from table1 deviceId = :deviceId order by recordedTime asc`

Comment: Have a look on `.deleteInBatch` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955672/how-can-i-delete-all-values-that-have-a-specific-column-and-row-number/62990535#62990535

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
@NamedQuery(name = FIND_COMMN_LOG_ID_BY_DEVICE_ID, query = "select entity from table1 entity where entity.deviceId =:deviceId ORDER BY recordedTime ASC"),

List entities = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Constants.FIND_COMMN_LOG_ID_BY_DEVICE_ID).setParameter("deviceId", id).execute(); 
entityRepository.deleteInBatch(entities);
```

Comment: here in the code, any JPA repository is not being used. Only i see the entity manager in the code. Is there any other way if i can do using entityManager ?

Comment: This will not work, IMO, because the named query returns ids and not entities. I'd be cautious too about that because loading thousands of entities just to delete them is wastefull (delete them directly, do not spend time fetching them, mapping them, caching them in the session, tracking them) just to delete them.

Comment: Ok, I didn't wrote the Named Query change sorry it is really complex : `select entity.id from table1 entity where entity.deviceId =:deviceId ORDER BY recordedTime ASC`=> `select entity from table1 entity where entity.deviceId =:deviceId ORDER BY recordedTime ASC`

Comment: OK, but there is NO way this could be faster than the original code. You have a massive amount of work fetching the entities that the original question code has not, and you have a massive batch of individual deletes that is not originally there either. The only upside I see (a big one) is that you won't blow a DB-side limit on size of the `IN` clause. E.g. Oracle limits the number of terms inside a `IN` clause at 1000 as I recall. The batch won't hit that limit, but at a tremendous cost.

Comment: It's just an purpose. I guess you have a better one, please teach us.

Comment: Sorry if I cam across as harsh. There are already two insightful comments by other users asking questions that can structurally affect what a good answer might be : is there on index on recorded time, how much time is spent in the delete vs the select clause, and why not issue the two requests into a single. I feel like there is no good answer I could provide without this extra information, that is key in understanding the issue as I see it.

Comment: It's ok...it seems index on recorded time. Seems select is not taking time. Only delete is taking time as there i am using list of 2000 records. Iteration is happening 2000 times as deletion query is happening 2000 times so it is taking time.

Comment: instead of execute delete query 2000 times, i am looking that if in one time or very less number of times, delete query  executes.

Comment: Yep `delete from table1 e where e.deviceId = :deviceId`

Comment: @user3278849 you should edit your question with those details, because these requests for clarification were made as comments to the question itself. By replying here, in the comments of Zorglube's answer, the people asking the question will not see you answered them. That being said, your code does not show 2000 individual delete requests. It shows a single delete request for a list of 2000 ids. Something does not add up.

Comment: here i am adding the limit for 2000 records  using .setMaxResults(2000) that i have specified in the query.

Comment: We do not understand each other. I understand you have 2000 records, but your code shows a single request to delete 2000 elements, and **not** 2000 requests to delete 1 element. It is one or the other, which is it ?

Comment: Yep, I think I've missed something.

Comment: @GPI, you're right, I answer to fast, so in the end @XtremeBaumer solution is better and correspond the enhanced vertion of mine `delete top 2000 from table1 e where e.deviceId = :deviceId order by recordedTime asc`.

Comment: Thanks all......i did not get any solution for this so decision to delete 2000 records is cancelled. i am following some another approach.

Comment: Thanks all for replying!!